# Silverlight Telerik RadTimeBar

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I've created a simple RadTimeBar with a LinearSparkline series:

```
<telerik:RadTimeBar x:Name="MainTimeBar" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows7" PeriodStart="1/1/2012" PeriodEnd="1/1/2013" SelectionStart="1/1/2012" SelectionEnd="1/1/2013" MinSelectionRange="28.00:00:00" IsSnapToIntervalEnabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionChanged="MainTimeBar_SelectionChanged">
    <telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
        <telerik:MonthInterval>
            <telerik:MonthInterval.IntervalSpans>
                <System:Int32>1</System:Int32>
            </telerik:MonthInterval.IntervalSpans>
        </telerik:MonthInterval>
        <telerik:DayInterval />
    </telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
    <telerik:RadLinearSparkline x:Name="chartTimeLine" XValuePath="{Binding TimeStamp}" YValuePath="{Binding Amount}" />            
</telerik:RadTimeBar>
```

This creates a timebar which only shows/can select months and should display some calculated amount for each month with a LinearSparkline chart inside.

I get the data through a webservice and set the itemsource in code-behind:

```
chartTimeLine.ItemsSource = e.Result;
```

but all I get in the chart is a straightline, no errors:

[image: Timebar]

Here's the class:

```
public class TimelineItem
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

TimeStamp is set to first day of each month and Amount is the calculation for it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you double checked that `e.Result` contains data? You could hard code some data rather than using the web service, which will eliminate one variable from the equation.

Comment: It does contain data for all 12 months. TimeStamp is set to first day of the month and the Amount holds some calculation for it. The data is there, double checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you set the XValuePath and YValuePath bindings. There's no need to add the Binding keyword, since they expect strings (the names of the properties you want to bind them to). Here's what I mean:

```
telerik:RadLinearSparkline x:Name="chartTimeLine" XValuePath="TimeStamp" YValuePath="Amount"
```

Also ensure that the Period (PeriodStart and PeriodEnd proeprties) you set is the one you want to see as per your data.

Kind Regards,
Evgenia